# SSIS exporting data to flat file renders double quotes as hexadecimal characters

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a simple SSIS job that exports data from the database to a flat file. I am using double quotes as text delimiters. When I run the job on my development machine everything exports fine. However, when I move the job to my staging server running Windows 2008 with SQL Server 2008 R2 the double quotes in the CSV file get exported as *X0022* (hexadecimal).

Does anyone know why that is and how to fix it?

Comment: It sounds like your development machine and staging server have different sql server service packs and/or updates installed.  On your staging server, open the problem package's flat file connection manager and check to see what the "Text qualifier" value is.  If this is the problem, you will see _x0022_ instead of " as the value.

Comment: David, I don't have Business Intelligence Development Studio on the staging machine (kind of want to keep it that way). Is there a way to open the flat file connection manager without it? Maybe a xml file or settings file?

Comment: Try opening the package with notepad, searching the xml for "TextQualifier" (there could be multiple lines depending on how many connection managers you have) and you should find the following line:
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="TextQualifier">_x0022_</DTS:Property>
Change it to
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="TextQualifier">"</DTS:Property>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like something we ran into a while back.  Jamie Thomson documented it in a blog post - [SQL Server 2008 SP1 CU 6 includes small changes to .dtsx files](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2011/10/11/31040.aspx).

Check the version of SQL Server in both environments:

```sql
SELECT @@VERSION
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst Tom's answer is correct it does not solve the problem if you can't make changes to any of the environments, ideally you want to make a change to the SSIS package so that it runs in all environments. How about this as a work around:

Add the following expression to the TextQualifier of the Flat File connection manager:

```
"\""
```

This will generate the required double quote text qualifier, however it is stored in the package xml as an expression which avoids the issue.

Answer (score 0):

just if it helps, I solved this issue creating a final step with a script task where I replace in the file generated all the "*x0022*" strings with the right value.