# How to assign a text qualifier in a flat file destination?

Tags: ssis, flat-file, qualifiers

We have an SSIS package which reads from a DB, creates a flat file from that info, and drops it to a file server.

I recently made an update to the package's query which is used against the DB, adjusted the column mappings, and placed it under the SQL Job which ran the SSIS package before.

The problem is that the text qualifier in the flat file should be a quotation mark: **"**. But when I checked the flat file it produced, the text qualifier showing is: **_*x0022*_**

I investigated the Text Qualifier property for the DestinationConnectionFlatFile, and it is set to a quotation mark: **"**

How can I ensure the flat file will have a text qualifier of quotation mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a previous answer I found when this happened to me:

[SSIS exporting data to flat file renders double quotes as hexadecimal characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7954939/236348)

Comment: This totally answers my question, but is there a way to fix this without updating SQL Server on the production server? If I roll back to the same version that is in production, make the changes to the package, and implement, will that solve the text qualifier issue?

Comment: If you look at the comments on the question itself, you can see a workaround involving editing the xml of the package itself and replacing the _x0022__ with a "

Answer (score 0):

Additionally ,

This issue occures because of installation issue.  So if you see this sort of Issue,  It mean if you are loading from file Database table and file contains 100 records , then instead of 100 records only 99  records would get loaded to database , last records would get skipped.

I had same issue, to fix that I had re-instalation of

1) MS Visual Studio 
2) MS BI Studio

in the sequence mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Given below are the two solutions :

Solution 1:  Open the Package in Notepad and Edit the Value present in the "TextQualifier" of particular object  to """.

object Name
"

Solution 2: open the Package and Replace the Value in the  "TextQualifier"  of the Flat File Connection Managers (FFD,SRC,SOURCE) to "\"".

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:  Open the Package in Notepad and Edit the Value present in the "TextQualifier" of particular object  to (") &quot follow semicolon

object Name
"

Thanks,
Prakash.A